# How can I use my getAge() method

Tags: java, implementation

[image]

I have to make this AgeDiscount class, which have a method that generates a Age Discount. So if I am 21 years old, I will get a discount of 21%.

So I need use my getAge from my Customer class. But I don't know how to pick it up?

```
public class AgeDiscount implements Discount {

    @Override
    public double getDiscountedPrice(double originalPrice) {

        return originalPrice;
    }

}
```

Comment: So, are you trying to get somebody else to do your homework?

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and if it doesn't work, then we can help you.

Comment: First i tried to make a new method in my Discount class. But the UML diagram says that i only need 1 Method. 

Then i tried to change the parameters in the getDiscountedPrice method to (double originalPrice, double age). But that gave my a fail.

Then i tried to catch .getAge in differnce way. 
Example customer.getAge.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it like this:

```
public class AgeDiscount implements Discount {

    private int age;

    public AgeDiscount (int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public double getDiscountedPrice(double originalPrice) {

        return (age / 100.0) * originalPrice;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

In customer class you can set it like this:

```
setDiscount(new AgeDiscount(getAge()));
```

or

```
this.discount = new AgeDiscount(getAge());
```